# How to update a textview in a dialog fragment from an activity?

Tags: android, dialog

It may be a silly question but I didn't find a good way to update a dialogfragment's textview from an activity in my android app.
What I'd like to do is to update the textview every second with a counter value and once the time elapsed, a Runnable closes the dialog fragment.
The dialog is closed once the time is elapsed, no problem but I cannot update the textview I want.

Here's my code for the dialog:

```
public class AlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String message = null;
private String title = null;
private ImageView imgV = null;
private TextView msgTv = null;
private TextView counterTv = null;
private  Button okBtn = null;
private int imageId = 0;
public static int AUTOMATIC_CLOSE = 100001;

private AlertDialogListener mDialogListener;

public void setImage(int i){
    imageId = i;
}

public void setContent(String ttl, String msg){
    message = msg;
    title = ttl;
}

public boolean hasContent(){
    return message != null && title != null;
}

public AlertDialog(){

}

public void performClick(){
    okBtn.performClick();
}

public void updateField(String text){
    counterTv.setText(text);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container);
    msgTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
    imgV = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
    counterTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.timeCounterDialog);

    if(imageId != 0)
        imgV.setImageResource(imageId);
    else
        imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.error_icon);

    if(hasContent()){
        msgTv.setText(message);
        getDialog().setTitle(title);
    }
    else{
        getDialog().setTitle("ERROR");
        msgTv.setText("An unexcepted error occured");
    }

    okBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.validateButton);

    okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mDialogListener != null){
                mDialogListener.onFinishedDialog();
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    mDialogListener.onStartedDialog();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mDialogListener = (AlertDialogListener) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mDialogListener = null;
    super.onDetach();
}

public interface AlertDialogListener{
    void onStartedDialog();
    void onFinishedDialog();
}

}
```

And this is how I launch it:

```
class myActivity extends Activity implements AlertDialogListener{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        """some init stuff"""
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            showAlertDialog();
        }
    }

@Override
public void onStartedDialog() {
    AutoCloseRunnable mAutoClose = new AutoCloseRunnable();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mAutoClose, 1000);

}

@Override
public void onFinishedDialog() {
    this.finish();
}

private void showAlertDialog(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog();
    mAlertDialog.setContent("No Connection available", "Please enable your internet connection.");
    mAlertDialog.setImage(R.drawable.error_icon);
    mAlertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");

}

private void updateAlertDialog(String text){
    mAlertDialog.updateField(text);
}

private void autoCloseAlertDialog(){
    mAlertDialog.performClick();
}


public class AutoCloseRunnable implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int closeCpt = 10;

        while(closeCpt >= 0){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                updateAlertDialog("Will close automatically in " + closeCpt + " seconds.");
                closeCpt--;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        autoCloseAlertDialog();
    }
}

}
```

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, simply use asynctask it's easier to handle UI updates like this.